# What is the "inner" force behind attracion/repulsion?

Tags: forces, charge, particle-physics

First of all, I'm sorry for any grammatical big error - English is not my native language.

I have a question that maybe does not have an answer beyond those which we already have, but maybe there is someone who can help me understand deeper than high-school level: what is exactly an electrical charge?

I already know something is charged (negative or positive) when it attracts or repulses another object or particle. But, stoping at that point, the electrical force coming from a charged body seems like magic.

I know it's analog to gravity: given at least 2 bodies with really big masses, they will one attract each other. So to friction/rubbing (similar forces to opposite sides)... But, why do all these happen?

Sintetizing: what exactly produces electrical attraction or repulsion? How can a particle move itself in one or another direction depending its "charge"?

Sorry for confusion...
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is exactly an electrical charge?

What *exactly* is (what we believe to be) a *fundamental* property or element of reality?

> why do all these happen?

Why is reality like it is?

I don't mean to seem mean but, rather, I wish to make clear that, unless we appeal to an infinite regress of more and more 'fundamental elements'  of reality, there must be at some point, one or more  *fundamental elements* of reality.

Clearly, if I could answer your question of "What is the “inner” force behind attracion/repulsion?", would you not wonder what is the *more* inner force behind that?

In other words, if you don't accept that electric charge and the electric interaction are fundamental, why would you accept that some 'inner' force behind that is fundamental?

Comment: Ok, I see your point. But it led me to another question: isn't there any present work searching some answer to it? Since science can only develop further if scientists keep doing the infinite regress, I think should be some mad researchers out there going for it.